# How do I backport/install a newer version of clang?

Tags: installation, clang

I just want to install the newest version of clang http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/clang-3.2

Does this mean I have to update my kernel to raring?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clang 3.2.1 is currently available for [12.04(Precise)](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-team/+archive/builds), [12.10(Quantal)](https://launchpad.net/~jkeiren/+archive/quantal/+build/4297283) on Launchpad.

[Clang 3.2.1 for 13.04(Raring)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/clang-3.2) is available from the universe repository and can be installed normally through Synaptic or apt.

For 12.04, You can add the PPA to your repository through Synaptic using the following line(with instructions provided in the link below):

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-team/builds/ubuntu precise main`

Or, from the command line(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kxstudio-team/builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang
```

For 12.10, you can either download the more recent deb files from [here](https://launchpad.net/~jkeiren/+archive/quantal/+build/4297283) and install with `sudo dpkg -i <package name>` or install from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~georgekola/+archive/clang).

To install the PPA on 12.10, run the following commands from the terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:georgekola/clang
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang
```

In Synaptic, add the following line:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/georgekola/clang/ubuntu quantal main

Note for the 12.10 packages: The deb files are named 3.2-1~exp5ubuntu1 from February 2013, while the PPA is 3.2-1~exp1ubuntu3 from December 2012. Personally, I am using clang 3.2.1 on 12.04 and cannot currently give a recommendation over which package to use on 12.10.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I also have backports for Quantal and Precise in [one of my PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/clang3.2-backports).

Comment: @George Edison Excellent! No reason why you shouldn't post this as an answer.

Comment: Well, currently there is bug with the packages - they depend on a couple of packages that require a GCC 4.7 build from one of my other PPAs. I'm working to remove all external dependencies from the PPA.

Comment: Just a note: Jeroen Keiren's PPA seems to work better for me on Quantal. The compilers in either PPA have a problem with using the `-fsanitize=undefined` flag, but I think that's a known issue.

Comment: @Nathan Are the newer versions of `clang` available for 12.04?

Comment: @Nickolai: I have no idea. To be honest, now that Trusty is out, I'm not really doing anything with 12.04 any more.

Comment: @NathanOsman Does Trusty have the very latest clang at the moment?